# Unable to use PFImageView in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, swift, parse-platform

I am using Parse SDK 1.6.0. I used storyboard and dragged an `UIImageView` to a custom `UITableViewCell`. When I connect the `UIImageView` to the swift file, I changed the class to `PFImageView`. However, Xcode keeps telling me "Use of undeclared type 'PFImageView'".

I checked and I found the `PFImageView.h` is in the `ParseUI.framework`. I also discovered that I am not able to use other things included in `ParseUI.framework` like `PFTableViewCell`. But I am able to use the `Parse.framework` like `PFUser`, `PFObject`, `PFFile` etc.

[image]

Can anyone help me out? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.
It worked after I added this line in the bridge file.

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you mean: `#import <ParseUI/ParseUI.h>`
This includes the ParseUI.framework which includes PFImageView

You will also need `#import <Parse/Parse.h>`
This includes the Parse.framework classes like PFUser, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to import the ParseUI on the class you are using, for example:

```
import ParseUI
```

You can then, on your Storyboard, select a normal ImageView, go to the Identity Inspector on your interface builder, change its class from UIImageView to PFImageView

Connect it as an outlet as normal to your code, but instead of connecting as a UIImageView ensure it is a PFImageView, like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imgTestImage :PFImageView!
```

You now have access to the PFImageView attributes such as:

```
let theImage = yourObject.valueForKey("profileImage") as? PFFile
imgTestImage.file = theImage
imgTestImage.loadInBackground()
```

Hope this helps